# Angular 7 loop Json array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a JSON file and want to fetch a key and value from it. How do I fetch both key and Value in Angular 7. I want to show in both template and controller class.
Example: I want to show "EX" which is the key and similarly want to display the "Test" name and the Value ["Star","star2"].

```
   {
 "EX":{
 "Test": ["Star","star2"],
 "Test2": ["Star","star2"],
 "Test3": ["Star","star4"]

  },



   "EX2":{
    "Test1": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test2": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test3": ["Star","star4"]

   },

   "EX3":{
    "Test4": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test5 ": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test6": ["Star","star4"]

    }



   }
```

I had tried this

```
     ._ctest=[]; // as a global variable
    public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/mydata.json")
     }

  this.getJSON().subscribe(result => {

   this._ctest=result;
    let allData=this._ctest;

     });
```

html file

```
    <div *ngFor="let data of allData | keyvalue">
    {{data.key}}
    <div *ngFor="let innerData of data.value | keyvalue"> 
    {{innerData.key}}: {{innerData.value}}
    </div>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

**TS**

```
let allData = {
 "EX":{
 "Test": ["Star","star2"],
 "Test2": ["Star","star2"],
 "Test3": ["Star","star4"]

  },
   "EX2":{
    "Test1": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test2": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test3": ["Star","star4"]

   },

   "EX3":{
    "Test4": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test5 ": ["Star","star2"],
    "Test6": ["Star","star4"]
    }
   }
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let data of allData | keyvalue">
    {{data.key}}
   <div *ngFor="let innerData of data.value | keyvalue"> 
     {{innerData.key}}: {{innerData.value}}
   </div>
</div>
```

I am considering that you have angular version 6 or above.

Comment: Yes I am using Angular 7..I tried your solutions and its not working..I have updated my questions

Comment: can you show me your `html` code where the loop is iterating.

Comment: Updated the question. Don't know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are using `allData` for iterating a a loop but it is a local var instead of global use `_ctest` instead of `allData`

Comment: One more thing, How do I do this same iteration in controller class?

Comment: by using a `forIn` loop or `foreach` loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193872/discussion-between-subham-and-yash-rami).

Comment: it would be great you do some R&D how the `ForIn` loop works. :) Otherwise i will add stackblitz link tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: https://medium.com/@baerree/angular-7-import-json-14f8bba534af

I think it is the same that you want.

Answer (score 0):

In think the main reason is you make it wrong.

```
._ctest=[]; // as a global variable
    public getJSON(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get("./assets/mydata.json")
     }

  this.getJSON().subscribe(result => {

   this._ctest=result;
    let allData=this._ctest;

     });
```

I dont understand your logic here by storing `result` to `_ctest` then storing `_ctest` to `allData`.

BUT>, You assigned `let allData=this._ctest;` and allData is a block scope how can on the template you can use `*ngFor="let data of allData`. There is ***NO*** allData here on the template bro.